# How to compare two dictionaries in python with list, string and integer?

Tags: python

```
results = {}
expectedResults = {}

results['a'] = 3
results['b'] = [1, 2]
results['c'] = '2A 04 73 74'

expectedResults['a'] = 3
expectedResults['b'] = [1, 2]
expectedResults['c'] = '2A 04 73 74'

compare = dict(set(results.items())-set(expectedResults.items()))
print(str(compare))
```

I get the following error.
**TypeError: list objects are unhashable**

I am using the following compare, so that the unmatched **key: value** pair (if any) shows in the print statement.

```
compare = dict(set(results.items())-set(expectedResults.items()))
```

Comment: You can test for equality using `results == expectedResults`. The example you provided is not very interesting. Can you modify it to have a mismatch and show the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because when you call  results.items(), it returns a list which is not a hashable.

A simple way to make your code work would be to iterate through each dict item and check for it's equality

```
for i in results:
if(results[i] !=  expectedResults[i]):
    print('different key : value pair')
    print('key : ' + i)
    print('Value in results : ' + str(results[i]))
    print('Value in expectedResults : ' + str(expectedResults[i]))
```

Your can't get a solution as simple as this.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: What is expected results has an additional key that results does not have?

Answer (score 0):

If lists are the only unhashable type in your dictionary, you could create dictionaries to use for comparison that convert lists to tuples:

```
results = {'a': 3, 'b': [1, 2], 'c': 'this is unmatched'}
expected_results = {'a': 3, 'b': [1, 2], 'c': 'blablabla'}

a_items = {k: tuple(v) if isinstance(v, list) else v for k, v in results.items()}
b_items = {k: tuple(v) if isinstance(v, list) else v for k, v in expected_results.items()}

compare = dict(set(a_items.items())-set(b_items.items()))
print(compare)
```

Output:

```
{'c': 'this is unmatched'}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could utilize difflib to find difference.

1. convert dict to string
2. check the difference between string

   ```
   import difflib
   import pprint
   results = {}
   expectedResults = {}

   results['a'] = 3
   results['b'] = [1, 2]
   results['c'] = '2A 04 73 74'

   expectedResults['a'] = 3
   expectedResults['b'] = [1, 2]
   expectedResults['c'] = 'test'

   print '\n'.join(difflib.ndiff(pprint.pformat(results).splitlines(), pprint.pformat(expectedResults).splitlines()))
   ```

   output:

   ```
   - {'a': 3, 'b': [1, 2], 'c': '2A 04 73 74'}
   ?                             ^^^^^^^^^^^

   + {'a': 3, 'b': [1, 2], 'c': 'test'}
   ?
   ```

Comment: Dictionaries do not necessarily guarantee the order of their inputs.